# How to make a PHP echo into a link

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I'm trying to get this so when I click the image, the image then shows in a new tab so it's able to be saved

I've tried adding the a href tags inside and around.

**Code:**

```
echo "<img src=" . random_image('css/avatars') . " />";
```

Comment: where you made the link? please share that code too?

Comment: You don't make any link in your code..... where's the problem? show us what  you obtain from your function random_image

Comment: what data on `$imageUrl`? because this code working properly

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question, accept the respective answer or post your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
echo '<a href="'. random_image('css/avatars') .'" target="_blank"><img src="' . random_image('css/avatars') . '" /></a>';
```

Comment: It's not opening the image in a new tab, it's just refreshing into a new tab.

https://gyazo.com/0c11469e6cb8d4f526be0cdd9749160d

Comment: Try now, I've changed link url.

Answer (score 2):

You should try

```
echo "<a target='_blank' href='".random_image('css/avatars')."'>"."<img src=" . random_image('css/avatars') . " /></a>";
```

I think this can help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not properly concatenating your string with what you get from *random_image* function.
You can try following code, here I am assuming that your *random_image* function returns complete path to your image

```
function random_image($path)
{
    // returning dummmy image
    return "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535498730771-e735b998cd64?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=623ed05afcc5a3fa1e444ffca95854dc&w=1000&q=80";
}

echo "<a href='".random_image('css/avatars')."' target='_blank'> <img src='".random_image('css/avatars')."' /></a>";
```